# componentDidUpdate likes component updates only on like

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, react-redux

I've created a play video page on which there is a video player with video info below it, like/unlike button, comment index and add comment form. Everything works properly except for div displaying the number of likes for a particular video. On like there is a difference in length of likes between prevProps and this.props so it updates the way it should, on unlike however, the length is the same for some reason remains the same even though the backend updates appropriately and the likes are never fetches. Any ideas as to why it's not working?

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        // console.log(prevProps.likes.length, this.props.likes.length)
        if (prevProps.likes.length !== this.props.likes.length) {
            this.props.fetchLikes();
            console.log(this.likesNumber());
        } else if (prevProps.comments.length !== this.props.comments.length) {
            this.props.fetchComments();
            this.commentsNumber();
        }
        
    }

    likesNumber() {
        if (!this.props.video) return null;
        const videoLikes = this.props.likes.filter(like => Object.values(like)[0].video_id == this.props.video.id);
        if (videoLikes.length === 1) {
            return "1 Like"
        } else {
            return `${videoLikes.length} Likes`
        }
    }
```

render method

```
render() {
        if (!this.props.video) { return null }
        const users = this.props.users;
        const videoLikes = this.props.likes.filter(like => Object.values(like)[0].video_id == this.props.video.id);
        const videoComments = this.props.comments.filter(comment => comment.video_id == this.props.video.id);
        const owner = users.filter(user => user.id === this.props.video.owner_id)[0];

        if (!owner) { return null };
        return (
            <div id="video-container">
                <video
                    className="video-player"
                    controls="controls"
                    src={this.props.video.video_url}
                    onPlay={this.playCount}
                    autoPlay="autoplay"
                    muted >
                    <div className="like"><Like id="like" video={this.props.video} props={this.props}/></div> 
                </video>
                <div id="play-info">
                    <div className="header-like">
                        <h1 className="play-title">{this.props.video.video_title}</h1>
                        <Like video={this.props.video} props={this.props}/>
                    </div>
                    <h2 className="play-date">{this.dateCreated(this.props.video.created_at)}</h2>
                    <div className="owner-name-initial">
                        <h2 className="owner-initial">{owner.username.split("")[0]}</h2> 
                        <h2 className="owner-name">{owner.username}</h2> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="video-info">
                        {/* <div className="play-count">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/48/000000/play.png" />
                            <h2 >{this.state.count}</h2>
                            <div className="hidden-views">{this.playNumber()}</div>

                        </div> */}
                        <div className="likes-count">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/like.png" />
                            <h2>{videoLikes.length}</h2>
                            <div className="hidden-likes">{this.likesNumber()}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="comments-count">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/50/000000/topic.png" />
                            <h2>{videoComments.length}</h2>
                            <div className="hidden-comments">{this.commentsNumber()}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h2 className="play-description">{this.props.video.video_description}</h2>
                </div>
                <CommentIndex video={this.props.video} history={this.props.history}/>
                <Comment video={this.props.video} history={this.props.history}/>
                <div className="home-footer">
                    <h2 className="home-footer-1">@2020</h2>
                    <h2 className="home-footer-2">
                        Made with
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" className="_3Weix"><path d="M10 18a1.23 1.23 0 01-.8-.4 14.25 14.25 0 00-4.4-3.7C2.5 12.3 0 10.7 0 7.5a5.52 5.52 0 011.6-3.9A5.73 5.73 0 016 2a5.25 5.25 0 014 1.9A5.85 5.85 0 0114 2c2.9 0 6 2.2 6 5.5s-2.5 4.8-4.8 6.4a15.51 15.51 0 00-4.4 3.7 1.23 1.23 0 01-.8.4z" fill="rgb(255,0,0)"></path></svg>
                            NYC
                        </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

likes controller

```
class Api::LikesController < ApplicationController
    
    def index
        @likes = Like.all
        render :index
    end

    def new
        @like = Like.new
        render :new
    end

    def show
        @like = Like.find(params[:id])
        render :show
    end

    def create
        @like = Like.new(like_params)
        @like.liker_id = current_user.id 
        if @like.save
            render :show
        else
            render json: @like.errors.full_messages , status: 422
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @like = Like.find(params[:id])
        @like.destroy
        render :index
        # respond_to do |f|
        #     f.html { redirect_to :index }
        #     f.json { head :no_content }
        # end
    end

    def like_params 
        params.require(:like).permit(:liker_id, :video_id)
    end

end
```

jbuilder partial / index / show

```
json.extract! like, :id, :liker_id, :video_id, :created_at

json.array! @likes do |like|
# @likes.each do |like|
    json.set! like.id do
        json.partial! 'like', like: like
    end
end

json.partial! 'like', like: @like
```

Comment: Since you tagged this as react-redux, have you checked that an action to update the store is firing when you ‘unlike’ and that the store is being updated?

Comment: the like(child) updates just fine and the play(parent) is not being updated on unlike